# How to display a numbering inside parentheses

Tags: pdftex, formatting, lists, nesting

I'd like to display the following numbering in LaTex:

```
(n-m) (a)... 

      (b)...
```

where n represents any section number and m the sequential number in this section. It can not be equation numbering because it would be placed on the right.

So for the third such structure in section 2, it will display as (2-3)(a). It is similar to theorem 2.3 which automatically numbers the 3rd theorem in section 2.

Comment: What you want to do is unclear. Could you explain more? A numbering of what?

Comment: Please also explain why you would prefer the bespoke numbering system in the preamble rather than in the body of the document.

Comment: I want to display (a) in the same line as the numbers. Please read it again.

Comment: Is this how you're wanting to number your equations, but the default equation numbering appears on the right?  Or are you numbering an enumerate in this environment?  Could you give an example of the source code where you would like this to appear in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be a starting point, using lists generated using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \restartlist{seclist}%
  \oldsection
}

\newlist{seclist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[seclist]{%
  label = {(\thesection-\arabic*)},
  widest = {(0-0)},
  align = left,
  resume
}
\newlist{secsublist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[secsublist]{%
  label = {(\alph*)},
  widest = (w),
  align = right
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{seclist}
  \item First item
  \item 
  \begin{secsublist}
    \item First nested item
    \item Second nested item
    \item Third nested item
    \item Final nested item
  \end{secsublist}
  \item Third item
  \item Final item
\end{seclist}

\begin{seclist}
  \item First item
  \item 
  \begin{secsublist}
    \item First nested item
    \item Second nested item
    \item Third nested item
    \item Final nested item
  \end{secsublist}
  \item Third item
  \item Final item
\end{seclist}

\section{Second section}

\begin{seclist}
  \item First item
  \item 
  \begin{secsublist}
    \item First nested item
    \item Second nested item
    \item Third nested item
    \item Final nested item
  \end{secsublist}
  \item Third item
  \item Final item
\end{seclist}

\end{document}
```

`seclist` would act like a `theorem` and define a `sec`tion `list` that includes the section number and a sequential numbering on a per-section basis. `secsublist` enumerates a sub-list with `\alph`abetic characters.